# Why does switchmap return a http response but map returns an observable

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

In this example, switchMap gives the http response but when map is used an Observable is returned. I believe this has to do with the 'flattening' switchMap does, but still don't understand what switchMap is doing behind the scenes to produce the http response result.

```
import{Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { of, from, Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap, switchMap, tap, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'star-wars',
  template: ``,
})
export class StarWars {
  private peopleUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    of(1)
    .pipe(
      map(() => this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')),
      // produces Observable {_isScalar: false, source: {…}

      switchMap(() => this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/1')),
      // produces http response {name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond"…}
    )
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
}
```

Any clarification on what switchMap is doing here to produce this different result would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'flattening' in Observables is similar concept to flattening arrays which you might be already familiar with.

For example:

```
[[0], [1, 2], [3]].flatten()
// output [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

In general flattening means taking Type of Types of values (e.g. array of arrays of values) and producing back Type of values (e.g. array of values).

Type of Types is sometimes call **higher-order Type** (e.g. higher-order function is a function returning function, higher-order Observable is a Observable of Observables). So flattening will convert higher-order type to first-order type.

Written in TypeScript `flatten` is a function with following signature:

```
flatten(source: Type<Type<Value>>): Type<Value>
```

In RxJS equivalent to `flatten` is **`mergeAll`** operator:

```
of(of(0), of(1, 2), of(3)).pipe(mergeAll())
// produce Observable<number> -> [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Combination of `map` and `flatten` is what is often call as **`flatMap`** although  the name can be different the main concept is the same - doing mapping and flattening as one action.

In array context instead of:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3].map(x => Array(x).fill(x)).flatten()
// [[], [1], [2, 2], [3, 3, 3]].flatten()
// output: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

We can just use:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3].flatMap(x => Array(x).fill(x))
```

RxJS has quite a few operators that act as **`flatMap`**:

- `mergeMap` - is flattening Observables concurrently so input and output values can be potentially in different order
- `concatMap` - is flattening Observables serially one at a time so input and output values will be in the same order
- `switchMap` - flattens Observable but delivers only the latest value

Generally these **`flatMap`** kind operators will simply call `subscribe` to the Observable returned from mapping function and will manage the underlying subscriptions for us.